# SwiftUI View lifecycle: View is initialized multiple times for no reason

Tags: swiftui, view, lifecycle

I have child SwiftUI Views that are initizailing the same view multiple times.
I drew up the stack to the ContentView and the first child is doubly initializaled then its children init 4 - 5 times!

Maybe this was always the case, but I'm whats going on.

**Called 2x !**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    var XXX

    @EnvironmentObject
    var XXX
...

    init() {
XXX
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { _ in

       ...
                {
                    ParlorView()
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .environmentObject(manager) 
                }

            } else {
                AnimatedLaunchView()
                    .environmentObject(manager)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Always been that way. See [Demystify SwiftUI performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10160/).

Comment: Thanks for the response and link @Yrb

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, `View` structs are lightweight value types so it's no problem to init many times. It's like declaring multiple `Int`, you wouldn't care about that.

I also noticed you have a mistake with unnecessary use of `.environmentObject` only a single parent `View` needs that then the child Views can access it. However, it looks like the object is a manager type and those are better as `EnvironmentKey`/`.environment` instead. See the [authorizationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/authorizationcontroller) environment value to get the idea.

```
struct AuthorizationControllerExample: View {
    @Environment(\.authorizationController) private var authorizationController
```

Comment: Tx for the explanation @mahal